# Handling data values filter(JS)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table, that I need to filter

Here is snippet

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $rows = $('tbody#report tr')
   
     var $filters = $('.table-filter').change(function(){
       var filterArr = $filters.filter(function(){
          return this.value
       }).map(function(){
          var $el = $(this);
          var value = $el.is('select') ? $el.find(':selected').text() :$el.val()  
          return {
            col: $el.data('col'),
            value: value.toLowerCase()
          }
       }).get();
       if(!filterArr.length){
         $rows.show()
       }else{
         $rows.hide().filter(function(){
            var $row = $(this)
            return filterArr.every(function(filterObj, i){
               var cellText = $row.find('td').eq(filterObj.col).text().toLowerCase();             
              return  cellText.includes(filterObj.value);
            })
         }).show()
       }
     })
   

});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/moment/moment/2.2.1/min/moment.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <h4>Date from</h4>
            <input type="date" class="table-filter form-control" id="datefilterfrom" data-date-split-input="true"  data-col="1">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <h4>Date to</h4>
            <input type="date"  class="table-filter form-control" id="datefilterto" data-date-split-input="true">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <h4>Project</h4>
           <select id="projectfilter" name="projectfilter" class="table-filter form-control" data-col="2">
             <option value="">Select one</option>
             <option value="1">Test project</option><option value="2">Test2</option></select>
        </div>
     <div class="col-md-2">
            <h4>Service</h4>
           <select id="servicefilter" name="servicefilter" class="table-filter form-control"  data-col="3">
             <option value="">Select one</option>
             <option value="1">Test service</option><option value="2">Test2 service</option></select>
        </div>
    </div>
<table id="testTable" class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">#</th>
                    <th scope="col">Date</th>
                    <th scope="col">Project</th>
                   <th scope="col">Service</th>
               
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="report">
              <tr>
                <td class="proposalId">9</td><td> 17/07/2018</td> <td> Test project</td><td> Test service</td>
              </tr>
              <tr><td class="proposalId">8</td><td> 18/07/2018</td><td> Test project</td><td> Test2  service</td></tr>
              <tr><td class="proposalId">7</td><td> 17/07/2018</td><td> Test2</td><td> Test2 service</td></tr>
              <tr style=""><td class="proposalId">3</td><td> 19/07/2018</td><td> Test2</td><td> Test service</td></tr>
              
    </tbody>
        </table>
```

It works great with text searches, it's 3 and 4 selectfields, but I cannot handle the date.

I was trying to do it like this

```
 var value = $el.is('select') ? $el.find(':selected').text() : moment($el.val(), "YYYY-MM-DD").format('DD/MM/YYYY')
```

But it not works correctly. How I can solve it?

Here is [my demo **codepen** snippet](https://codepen.io/suhomlineugene/pen/XBoqyj), you can use to test it

Comment: There are too many issues with this code to point out a single answer to your question. 

First of all, you're missing the 'table-filter' class on the date elements. Secondly, the format of the dates don't match the format of the value you're searching for. Finally, your program only compares the start and end against the list, it doesn't do anything to determine if the date is within a range. 

The best way to do that will be to convert the date to a timestamp, then use logical operators to determine whether the date falls within a certain range.

Comment: I edited classes@nickolusroy

Answer (score 2):

Well there are many things to correct in your code:

- The logic you are using to filter the data in the table is wrong, **if
  an `input` value is changed the whole filter is reset** taking only only
  this input value into account, you need to change the logic
  behind that.
- For example for getting a `select` value you just need `$el.val()`
  instead of writing `$el.is('select') ? $el.find(':selected').text() :$el.val()`.

And you need to handle `dates` separately in your `filter` code, because `.includes()` will be comparing `strings`, so you need to calculate and compare `date` objects here.

This is how should be your date comparison code:

```
if ($el.prop('type') == 'date') {
  return filterArr.every(function(filterObj, i) {
    var cellText = $row.find('td').eq(filterObj.col).text().toLowerCase();
    if ($el.prop('id') == "datefilterfrom") {
      return new Date(filterObj.value) <= new Date(cellText.split("/")[2], +cellText.split("/")[1] - 1, cellText.split("/")[0]);
    }
    if ($el.prop('id') == "datefilterto") {
      return new Date(filterObj.value) >= new Date(cellText.split("/")[2], +cellText.split("/")[1] - 1, cellText.split("/")[0]);
    }
  })
}
```

**Note:**

For the `date` inputs you need to pass `1` as `col` value in your filter object because you have only one date column in your table:

```
if ($el.prop('type') == 'date') {
    return {
      col: 1,
      value: value.toLowerCase()
    }
}
```

**Demo:**

This is an updated working demo.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $rows = $('tbody#report tr')

  var $filters = $('.table-filter').change(function() {
    var $el = $(this);
    var filterArr = $filters.filter(function() {
      return this.value
    }).map(function() {
      var value = $el.val();
      if ($el.prop('type') == 'date') {
        return {
          col: 1,
          value: value.toLowerCase()
        }
      }
      return {
        col: $el.data('col'),
        value: value.toLowerCase()
      }
    }).get();
    if (!filterArr.length) {
      $rows.show()
    } else {
      $rows.hide().filter(function() {
        var $row = $(this);
        if ($el.prop('type') == 'date') {
          return filterArr.every(function(filterObj, i) {
            var cellText = $row.find('td').eq(filterObj.col).text().toLowerCase();
            if ($el.prop('id') == "datefilterfrom") {
              return new Date(filterObj.value) <= new Date(cellText.split("/")[2], +cellText.split("/")[1] - 1, cellText.split("/")[0]);
            }
            if ($el.prop('id') == "datefilterto") {
              return new Date(filterObj.value) >= new Date(cellText.split("/")[2], +cellText.split("/")[1] - 1, cellText.split("/")[0]);
            }
          })
        } else {
          return filterArr.every(function(filterObj, i) {
            var cellText = $row.find('td').eq(filterObj.col).text().toLowerCase();
            return cellText.includes(filterObj.value);
          })
        }
      }).show()
    }
  })


});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/moment/moment/2.2.1/min/moment.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <h4>Date from</h4>
    <input type="date" class="table-filter form-control" id="datefilterfrom" data-date-split-input="true" data-col="1">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <h4>Date to</h4>
    <input type="date" class="table-filter form-control" id="datefilterto" data-date-split-input="true">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <h4>Project</h4>
    <select id="projectfilter" name="projectfilter" class="table-filter form-control" data-col="2">
      <option value="">Select one</option>
      <option value="1">Test project</option>
      <option value="2">Test2</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <h4>Service</h4>
    <select id="servicefilter" name="servicefilter" class="table-filter form-control" data-col="3">
      <option value="">Select one</option>
      <option value="1">Test service</option>
      <option value="2">Test2 service</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
<table id="testTable" class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">Date</th>
      <th scope="col">Project</th>
      <th scope="col">Service</th>

    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="report">
    <tr>
      <td class="proposalId">9</td>
      <td> 17/07/2018</td>
      <td> Test project</td>
      <td> Test service</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="proposalId">8</td>
      <td> 18/07/2018</td>
      <td> Test project</td>
      <td> Test2 service</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="proposalId">7</td>
      <td> 17/07/2018</td>
      <td> Test2</td>
      <td> Test2 service</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="">
      <td class="proposalId">3</td>
      <td> 19/07/2018</td>
      <td> Test2</td>
      <td> Test service</td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: For example date , great, but project and service not

Comment: @EugeneSukh Yes, that's because you are doing things in a wrong way each time an input is changed the filter is reset to handle only this input value, you need to change the logic behind.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var value = $el.is('select') ? $el.find(':selected').text() : moment($el.val().replace(/(\d{2})\/(\d{2})\/(\d{4}).*/, '$3-$2-$1'), "YYYY-MM-DD").format('DD/MM/YYYY')
```

for example

```js
 document.write(("17/07/2018").replace(/(\d{2})\/(\d{2})\/(\d{4}).*/, '$3-$2-$1'))
```